# 7" tablet is taking 10" layout

Tags: android-layout

I have a problem with device picking wrong layout. 
I have defined my layouts as per the screen size and grouped them under following - 
 layout-sw600dp, layout-sw720dp and layout-sw480dp.

I have two 7" tablets for sw600dp.

1- Samsung 7" galaxy tab -  This device is taking correct layout as those defined in layout-sw600dp.

2- Another 7" device [ordered from a distributor in China]- This one is taking 10" layout.

When I use http://www.whatismyscreenresolution.com/ both the devices give 1024x600 .

To check I programmatically retrieved Smallest Screen Width and Screen Width [getResources().getConfiguration().smallestScreenWidthDp and screenWidthDp]. On 2nd device  I get values as 720 and 1024.

Any idea as how can I proceed further to make sure that my second device also takes layouts defined under layout-sw600dp .

regards
Pradeep

Answer (score 0):

what does this code returns on that device ?

```
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    String pxSize = dm.widthPixels + " x " + dm.heightPixels;
```

it may show 720x1024.
that's because even if the screen has a physic size of 600x1024px,  what you get from those methods are values set by manufacturers. There is possibly a difference between those set values and real values.

If this is the case, there no much you can do about it.
except may be

```
 if ( "aTargetManufacturer".equals( android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER )  )
 {
     useAnotherLayout();
 }
```

but that's clearly not good practice.

Comment: does the display metric return 720x1024 ?